# I need to setup an app that uses Postgres and Python Social Auth?

Tags: python, postgresql, socialauth

I am starting to develop an app using Django as a framework. I will be using  Python Social Auth  https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth to login using Facebook.

The app will use Postgres as a database, therefore I am looking for guidance in the sequence to use to install the initial setup. The application will be deployed in Heroku and I found a references https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql  in how to install Postgres in my machine and in the hosting.

I need to find the right sequence of installation to be able to have a fully operational setup, before start to add my application.

Does anybody has experience in such configuration?

Comment: I don't really understand what this has to do with PostgreSQL. It seems like you are getting confused about different layers in the application, but it's hard to tell from the information provided. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is borderline close as off topic, asking for tutorial, but, the main answer to your question is the tutorial from heroku on [heroku on django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) This covers getting a simple hello world app up and running and using postgres (including being able to run it locally via heroku local).  The one thing I would add is that I prefer to modify my settings.py to look like this:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASE = { } # standard postgres for local configuration

if dj_database_url.config(): #override local for heroku set value
   DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

At the conclusion of this tutorial, you'll have a working app that can use postgres.  After that, installing Facebook social auth mainly consists of registering your app to get some secret values and putting those in settings.py as described in the documentation.  (Truth in lending, haven't used Facebook auth but have done Google and Twitter Auth.  The main thing with Heroku is that I would strongly recommend adding 127.0.0.1:5000 as well as https://.herokuapps.com so you can debug stuff from your local instance first (and also make sure you leave the default django auth so you can still log in via username/password while you're troubleshooting)

(One last tip: you should be able to do heroku run python manage.py shell and then from there do something like:

```
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  u = User.objects.get(username="Your Facebook username")
  u.is_staff = True
  u.is_superuser = True
  u.save()
```

To promote your facebook account to be admin, as I forget if social auth sets it up so first user account is admin automatically or not)